# Is it safe to do server side (python3/flask) caching of JSON Web Key Sets (JWKS) from Auth0 for a minute or so?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jwt, auth0

I'm fetching the [JWKS](https://auth0.com/docs/jwks) from `https://X.auth0.com/.well-known/jwks.json` server side. I'm wondering if it is safe to cache them for some minutes, because it seems wasteful to constantly barrage that end-point with gets.

I'm using flask and was planning on caching it by doing something simple like:

```
@cache.cached(timeout=60, key_prefix='auth0/%s')
def get_jwks():
    return requests.get("https://" + AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/.well-known/jwks.json").json()
```

The rest of the implementation is heavily inspired by the [auth0 tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/python/01-authorization).

The caching mechanism comes from the library `flask_caching`, which says:

> You are able to use this decorator with any
>           function by changing the `key_prefix`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A JWKS is an Auth0 concept. It contains the public key set to verify the signature of the issued tokens

> At the most basic level, the JWKS is a set of keys containing the public keys that should be used to verify any JWT issued by the authorization server.

A public key can be safely published. It only will change when a new key pair is generated. I do not know how is the process of renewing a key: manual or automatic. But  you can cache it perfectly. Just ensure to download the public key after a failed verification if the reason is a bad public key